# Array of files' links is empty in Mongodb after asynchronous operations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, asynchronous, apollo

My Apollo mutation function gets 2 arrays of files as arguments. Then I write it into filesystem, pushing their location into arrays. After that I want the arrays to be written in MongoDB, but mongo has empty fields because of asynchrony.
How can I handle that?

```
const { createWriteStream } = require("fs");
const path = require('path');
const Post = require('../../models/Post');
const checkAuth = require('../../utils/check-auth');

module.exports = {
  Mutation: {
    async addPost(_, { postInput: { title, description, pictures, panoramas, price, location } }, ctx) {
      const anon = checkAuth(ctx);
      let pics = [];
      let pans = [];

      pictures.map(async (el) => {
        const { createReadStream, filename } = await el;

        await new Promise(res =>
          createReadStream()
            .pipe(createWriteStream(path.join("static/images", filename)))
            .on("close", res)
        );
        pics.push(`static/images/, ${filename}`);
      })
      panoramas.map(async (el) => {
        const { createReadStream, filename } = await el;

        await new Promise(res =>
          createReadStream()
            .pipe(createWriteStream(path.join("static/images", filename)))
            .on("close", res)
        );
        pans.push(path.join("static/images", filename));
      })

      const newPost = new Post({
        title,
        description,
        price,
        pictures: pics,
        panoramas: pans,
        createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
        userId: anon.id,
        location,
      });

      const res = await newPost.save();
      console.log(res)
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just wait until all the promises resolve and only then proceed to create a new document.

```
async function addPost(_, {postInput: {title, description, pictures, panoramas, price, location}}, ctx) {
    const anon = checkAuth(ctx);
    let pans = [];
    let pics = [];

    pictures.map(async (el) => {
        pics.push(
            new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                const {createReadStream, filename} = await el;

                await new Promise(res =>
                    createReadStream()
                        .pipe(createWriteStream(path.join("static/images", filename)))
                        .on("close", res)
                );
                resolve(`static/images/, ${filename}`);
            })
        )
    });

    await Promise.all(pics);

    panoramas.map(async (el) => {
        pans.push(
            new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                const {createReadStream, filename} = await el;

                await new Promise(res =>
                    createReadStream()
                        .pipe(createWriteStream(path.join("static/images", filename)))
                        .on("close", res)
                );
                resolve(path.join("static/images", filename));
            }));
    });

    await Promise.all(pans);

    const newPost = new Post({
        title,
        description,
        price,
        pictures: pics,
        panoramas: pans,
        createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
        userId: anon.id,
        location,
    });

    const res = await newPost.save();
    console.log(res)
    return true;
}
```

This is a quick example, I recommend you clean this up a bit and add error handling of some sort to it.